# Determine the position of the charge for equilibrium

Tags: electromagnetism, homework, electrostatic

**Question:**

> A system of three electric charges lying in a straight line is in equilibrium. Two of the charges are positive with magnitude Q and 2Q, and are 50 cm apart. Determine the sign, magnitude and position of the third charge.

I am considering a negative charge in between the Q and 2Q, lets say q, and equating the force due to charge Q and 2Q on the charge q. Then I calculate the distance of q from charge Q as 20.7 and from charge 2Q as 29.3, but that is not the answer given.

The answer given is like this:
q shoulb be a negative charge with magnitude 0.08Q and located at x = 54.15 cm from Q and 4.14 cm from 2Q

What mistake am I making? Can anyone help me?

Comment: The "correct answer" doesn't make sense. If there is a negative charge to the left (or right) of two positive charges, they will not be in equilibrium in terms of forces. Clearly, the negative charge will be attracted towards both positive charges to the right or left of it. Is the negative charge fixed in position somehow?

Comment: @jonk Thanks ......but in the solution they have calculated by potential energy

Comment: For potential energy, I gather: \$k\frac{1\:\textrm{Q}\cdot 2\:\textrm{Q}}{50\:\textrm{cm}}+k\frac{1\:\textrm{Q}\cdot q}{50\:\textrm{cm}+d}+k\frac{2\:\textrm{Q}\cdot q}{d}=0\$ (picking the 2Q charge as my zero reference for 'd' with the 1Q charge on the minus axis side.) Your solution is one possible solution. But there's more than one solution. So I think by "equilibrium" they must have not meant "unchanging in relative position" but instead meant that, barring collisions, they will eventually return to the same positions again. Can you add anything on that point?

Comment: @jonk The question asks for the *position* of the 3rd charge. This suggests that the charges occupy fixed relative positions.

Answer (score 0):

The equilibrium is not stable, but it's possible like a pyramid standing upside down in a perfect balance.

The positive charges push each other as much as the negative charge pulls them. In addition the negative charge must get the same pull from both positive charges.

Write these as equations. This can also be formulated as a potential well or merely potential enerqy terrace (=flat point) but I believe it finally reduces to the same equations when you try to determine, where the derivative of the potential enerqy vs. position is zero and can be zero.